# Visibility of the meta site as a distinct site

Tags: feature-request

I would like to state that the visibility of the meta site is somewhat low. I clearly didn't read the FAQ to the bottom, however I don't think this will be all that uncommon (some of the questions start to seem a little obvious to those familiar with forums). I didn't realize that the "meta" link at the top was to a website with questions relating to the website (as opposed to programming). I had probably 400-500 reputation before I figured out that this was a separate site and that searching on Stack Overflow would not search here.

Suggestions:

- Move the Stack Overflow FAQ that describes meta up in the list (or create a new one).
- Provide a tooltip on the meta link describing what meta is referring to (namely a site for questions about the Stack Overflow site rather than about programming).
- Make the search on Stack Overflow also pick up questions in the meta site. I'm not sure how to make it clear which results are from meta vs Stack Overflow, but perhaps some sort of coloring would do the trick.

Comment: There's a link at the top of every page... it's not that low.

Comment: @Ben Yes, I know. Just edited to make it more clear. I was not aware what meta meant, and since I didn't realize it was useful I just didn't click the link. I like to learn about things bit by bit, so I figured I would browse questions and learn about features as I went. Since I did not click on the meta link, I didn't realize what it was for.

Comment: So frm ym understanding, you're not saying that once you'd found meta you didn't know what it was but rather that you weren't aware of the existence of meta or realise the significance of the `meta` link at the top of the page? Although I didn't have that issue myself (I'm an inveterate FAQ reader), I can see your point

Comment: Yes, exactly correct.

Comment: There is also the fact that "meta" is not a common word that people from non-English-speaking country will know about when mentioned for the first time.

Answer (score 3):

The Meta link looks very visible to me:

[image: Rob W 63,498 7 45 88 286 review chat meta faq]

The role of the site is also clearly described in the [Meta site FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq). The top section is:

> #### [What kind of questions can I ask here?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)
>
> If your question is about:
>
> - [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

- [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/)
- [Stack Overflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/)
- [Promotions & Advertising](https://stackexchange.com/about/contact)
- Support, feature requests, or bug reports for the core Stack Exchange engine that powers [all Stack Exchange websites](https://stackexchange.com/sites)

> … it is welcome here.

Comment: I should have been more clear on that point. "meta" is a sort of vague term that I didn't realize meant site about the site.

Comment: @CrazyCasta Did you read the meta faq? It seems to give a clear, concise explanation of the site's role on a prominent place (the top of the meta [FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) page).

Comment: I did not realize that the meta site was even a different site, so I assumed that the FAQ was the same. In particular I believe my first experience was from a link from the FAQ. I just assumed that clicking FAQ would take me back to the same FAQ.

Comment: And you thought that the different (grey-ish) logo was a result of the shortage of ink? ;)

Comment: I may not be articulating my point well. I think the largest confusion was that the search on Stack Overflow was not searching meta. Wrt your logo point, I sort of thought that these posts were somehow special cases that existed on Stack Overflow with some sort of special tag or something. That is, that they were so rare I just hadn't seen them in the question list.